# How to stop playing current song when changing scene?

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a school project now, creating a game based on JavaFX. I have an issue with my audio clip setting. When I change the scene from one to another, I want the song to stop playing. Then, after moving to the next scene, I want to play different songs from my audio set. If possible, I would like to set the program to play different songs after one is played. Please help me. Thank you.

In the first scene, I made one song playing all the time, infinite loop. From there, I tried to think whenever I am moving on to the next scene, I will stop playing the current song and start playing a different song from the playlist. But, `.stop()` doesn't work, if I put it in my method which creates a new scene.

```
String path = "E:\\All Computer Science Materials\\Java 240 Project\\Music\\"
            + songs.getSong(0) + ".mp3";
    Media media = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());

    currentPlay = new AudioClip(media.getSource());
    currentPlay.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
    currentPlay.play();
loading.setOnAction(e ->stageOne.setScene(scenePlay));
```

Comment: How about providing some code?

Comment: This is not the entire code though. I am trying to stop the music right after the e ->stageOne.setScene(scenePlay) is called.

Comment: It is not really related to your question (and for this I advise you to make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), but why did you choose `AudioClip` compared to `MediaPlayer` especially for playing music during a long time ?

Comment: `loading.setOnAction(e ->{currentPlay.stop(); stageOne.setScene(scenePlay);});`